# How to stop drawing GridView items BEFORE the parent View becomes scrollable?

Tags: java, android, gridview, viewflipper

I'm trying to populate a `ViewFlipper` with a `GridView`, but with a paging capability rather than scrolling. The `GridView` will fill out a single "page" (one complete page without scrolling), and start filling out the next View in the `ViewFlipper` with the next bit of the data set.

I need to dynamically fill the pages, as the screen sizes will vary. This `GridView` sports a custom  adapter class with a `getView()` override, so I was thinking the most elegant solution would be to draw the view as normal in the `GridView`, but this is where I run into some confusion:

Two things:

How can i tell the `getView()` function to write the `GridView` items to the next `View` in the `ViewFlipper`? And by that token, how can I know when the screen fills to just before the scroll bar pops up (I don't want scrollable lists, which was the whole point in using a `ViewFlipper`).

Or is there a better solution that i just haven't found yet?  I couldn't find an example in the API demos and little info here on stackoverflow except this, which got me started, but I still need the above two suggestions to make this solution work (unless there's something better): [Android ViewFlipper not flipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563749/android-viewflipper-not-flipping)

The GridView adapter:

```
// custom adapter made for the GridView
public class ButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Map<String, String>> mData;
    private int mLayout;

    public ButtonAdapter(Context c, int layout, List<Map<String, String>> list) {
        this.mContext = c;
        this.mData = list;
        this.mLayout=layout;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Button btn = null;

        if(convertView==null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(this.mLayout, null);
        }

        btn = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_btn);
        if(btn != null) {
            //btn.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
            btn.setText(mData.get(position).get("label"));
            btn.setId(position);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```