# viewflipper flipping

Tags: android, viewflipper

I have a viewflipper and two buttons "next" and "previous" outside the viewflipper. I want viewflipper to show next background on clicking "next" and previous background on clicking "previous". How can I do that?

Comment: just have a look at my answer.

Comment: See the Posible Duplicate Answer at the link below:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563749/android-viewflipper-not-flipping/5920503#5920503][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563749/android-viewflipper-not-flipping/5920503#5920503

Comment: See the Posible Duplicate Answer at the link :
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563749/android-viewflipper-not-flipping/5920503#5920503][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563749/android-viewflipper-not-flipping/5920503#5920503

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two techniques to achieve your requirements.

**1.** Use **showPrevious** and **showNext** methods of **ViewFlipper** class. One thing you have to know about these methods is by calling any method continuously, it will start displaying it's children in ascending order for **showNext** and descending order for **showPrevious**.

Example : View flipper has 4 children say 0, 1, 2, 3. Initially it will display first item i.e., child 0. Now if you called showNext 6 times continuously, it starts displaying 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2. So finally it will display child 2. Same procedure in descending order for shoePrevious also.

**2.** Use **setDisplayedChild** method to display a particular child included in the ViewFlipper.

Example: The view flipper may as below in XML layout file

```
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/flipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <include android:id="@+id/first"  layout="@layout/first_view" />
    <include android:id="@+id/second"  layout="@layout/second_view" />
</ViewFlipper>
```

To display first child you can use **setDisplayedChild** in two ways.

call `setDisplayedChild(R.id.first);` or `setDisplayedChild(0);` means you can use Id of child in ViewFlipper or position of child in ViewFlipper.

So depending on actual requirements, decide which method is appropriate.

I hope you understand this.

Answer (score 2):

By viewFlipper.showPrevious() and viewFlipper.showNext() you can do this .

Answer (score 2):

you need to do the following:

```
nextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            viewFlipper.showNext();
        }
    });
}
```

and the same for the previous button.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `yourViewFlipper.showNext()` or `yourViewFlipper.showPrevious()` in your next and previous button click handlers.